# How to populate the source NULL values in an integer data type column as NULL in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

In the source file I have null values for a column X. But the datatype of the column X in the target table is INTEGER.I using fastload to load from the source file to the target table. Since the default value of integer is '0', its populating 0 in the target for the source null values. But I want to populate null in the target table for the null values in source file. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: How do the NULLs look like in the source file? If it's an empty string use NULLIF: `DEFINE ... intcol(VARCHAR(11), NULLIF =  '')`

Comment: Remove the default constraint.  It sounds like you don't want them.